# Phalcon install on CodeAnywhere

Tags: phalcon, codeanywhere

I have tried everything to install Phalcon in a stack of my CodeAnywhere account -- and cannot accomplish it. I was wondering if anyone here was successful in doing it, and if he/she can share how.

I am new in this community which has been extremely helpful to me, and I joined to contribute back in gratitude for all the answers I have read here.

I searched first for to see if others had the same issue (concerning installing in CodeAnywhere) but did not see any, so I posted this question.

Answer (score 0):

use this help:

https://phalconphp.com/pl/download/linux

i just add apt source and install from package. works perfectly

Comment: hi, thank you so much for your tip -- but i tried everything stated in the phalconphp website, its forum, but nothing. It why i wanted to ask if anyone has accomplished it in that server. The host installed it but did not tell me how they did it. I did not want that done for me, I want to know how it is done. I just want to know which command line command  gets this done. --- apt-get gives an error.